# How to calculate total difference in milliseconds by condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following pandas dataframe `df`:

| timestamp | version | actual | pred |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-19 11:00:00.600 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-01-19 11:00:00.800 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-01-19 11:00:01.200 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-01-19 11:00:01.800 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-01-19 11:00:02.200 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-01-19 11:00:02.600 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-01-19 11:00:03.200 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-01-19 11:00:03.600 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-01-19 11:00:03.800 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-01-19 11:00:03.600 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-01-19 11:00:03.800 | 4 | 0 | 1 |

I need to calculate the total distance in milliseconds between values of `1` in `actual` and `pred`, grouped by `version`.

The expected answer is: 1000 ms

- version 1: (2022-01-19 11:00:01.200 - 2022-01-19 11:00:00.600) = 400 ms
- version 2: (2022-01-19 11:00:02.200 - 2022-01-19 11:00:02.200) = 0 ms
- version 3: (2022-01-19 11:00:03.800 - 2022-01-19 11:00:03.200) = 600 ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there exists a single "actual" and single "pred" values for each "version", we could simply subtract values. In other words, if each "version" has exactly 1 "actual" and exactly 1 "pred" value, then `df['actual'].eq(1)` will be True for exactly one value per "version"; same for `df['pred'].eq(1)`. Since the data is sorted by "version", the versions match.

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
out = ((df.loc[df['actual'].eq(1), 'timestamp'].to_numpy() - 
        df.loc[df['pred'].eq(1), 'timestamp'].to_numpy())
       .astype('timedelta64[ms]').sum())
```

If not all versions have a 1 in either of "actual" or "pred", we could still filter the "actual" and "pred" values; then merge on "version" (so that each "version" will have an "actual" and a "pred" value); then find difference and `sum`:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
merged = (df.loc[df['actual'].eq(1), ['version', 'timestamp']]
          .merge(df.loc[df['pred'].eq(1), ['version', 'timestamp']], 
                 on='version', suffixes=('_actual', '_pred')))

out = (merged['timestamp_actual'] - merged['timestamp_pred']).astype('timedelta64[ms]').sum()
```

Output:

```
1000
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please clarify how the grouping by `version` works in your proposed solution?

Comment: In other words, the differences should only be calculated within same values of `version`.

Comment: In my real dataset the data is not sorted by `version`, because `version` is string. Also sometimes for the same `version` there might be all zeros of `actual` or `pred`. My honest apologies for this update. I've just have not considered its importance.

Comment: @Fluxy but each version will have at most one 1, correct?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: @Fluxy I edited with a version that should work in that case.